# Correct way to add full-width text box between a horizontal line and two minipage-based columns

Tags: spacing

I need to add a "headline" to my resume (a full-width text container below the name section). I'm not sure what is the correct way to do this. It would be between a custom "namesection" command defined this way:

```
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1 
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #2
% \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
} \\[5pt]
\centering{
\color{headings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
\vspace{-15pt}
}
```

and a two-column section, with the left column defined like this: `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}`.
Attached is what it looks like when I simply add the headline text. I'm sure there is something better than plain text with the correct vertical spacing figured out.
[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.